# ERROR = SQL state: 42703 while trying to insert data into my table

Tags: sql, state

I have a SQL state:

> 42703 ERROR (ERROR:  column "datereq" of relation "eventrequest" does not exist)

while trying to insert data into my table. But I don't see any issue. Can you please help? It is the DATEREQ values that don't seem to match with the DateReq column in the "eventrequest" table.

Below is the code I have written

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE EventRequest 
(EventNo VARCHAR(8) CONSTRAINT EventNoNotNull NOT NULL, 
 DateHeld DATE CONSTRAINT DateHeldNotNull NOT NULL, 
 DateReq DATE CONSTRAINT DATEREQNotNull NOT NULL, 
 CustNo VARCHAR(8) CONSTRAINT CustNoNotNull NOT NULL, 
 FacNo VARCHAR(8) CONSTRAINT FacNoNotNull NOT NULL, 
 DateAuth DATE, 
 Status VARCHAR(10) CONSTRAINT StatusNotNull NOT NULL CHECK (Status IN('pending','Denied','Approved')),
 EstCost DECIMAL(12,2) CONSTRAINT EstCostNotNull NOT NULL, 
 EstAudience INTEGER CONSTRAINT EstAudienceNotNull NOT NULL CHECK (EstAudience>0),
 BudNo VARCHAR(10),
  CONSTRAINT PK_EVENTREQUEST PRIMARY KEY (EventNo),
CONSTRAINT FK_FACNO FOREIGN KEY (FacNo) 
   REFERENCES FACILITY (FacNo),
CONSTRAINT FK_CUSTNO FOREIGN KEY (CustNo) 
   REFERENCES CUSTOMER (CustNo) );
```

Data input:

```
Insert into EVENTREQUEST (EVENTNO,DATEHELD,DATEREQ,CUSTNO,FACNO,DATEAUTH,STATUS,ESTCOST,ESTAUDIENCE,BUDNO) values ('E100','2018-10-25','2018-06-06','C100','F100','2018-06-08','Approved',5000,80000,'B1000');
Insert into EVENTREQUEST (EVENTNO,DATEHELD,DATEREQ,CUSTNO,FACNO,DATEAUTH,STATUS,ESTCOST,ESTAUDIENCE,BUDNO) values ('E101','2018-10-26','2018-07-28','C100','F100',NULL,'Pending',5000,80000,'B1000');
Insert into EVENTREQUEST (EVENTNO,DATEHELD,DATEREQ,CUSTNO,FACNO,DATEAUTH,STATUS,ESTCOST,ESTAUDIENCE,BUDNO) values ('E103','2018-09-21','2018-07-28','C100','F100','2018-08-01','Approved',5000,80000,'B1000');
Insert into EVENTREQUEST (EVENTNO,DATEHELD,DATEREQ,CUSTNO,FACNO,DATEAUTH,STATUS,ESTCOST,ESTAUDIENCE,BUDNO) values ('E102','2018-09-14','2018-07-28','C100','F100','2018-07-31','Approved',5000,80000,'B1000');
Insert into EVENTREQUEST (EVENTNO,DATEHELD,DATEREQ,CUSTNO,FACNO,DATEAUTH,STATUS,ESTCOST,ESTAUDIENCE,BUDNO) values ('E104','2018-12-03','2018-07-28','C101','F101','2018-07-31','Approved',2000,12000,'B1000');
Insert into EVENTREQUEST (EVENTNO,DATEHELD,DATEREQ,CUSTNO,FACNO,DATEAUTH,STATUS,ESTCOST,ESTAUDIENCE,BUDNO) values ('E105','2018-12-05','2018-07-28','C101','F101','2018-08-01','Approved',2000,10000,'B1000');
Insert into EVENTREQUEST (EVENTNO,DATEHELD,DATEREQ,CUSTNO,FACNO,DATEAUTH,STATUS,ESTCOST,ESTAUDIENCE,BUDNO) values ('E106','2018-12-12','2018-07-28','C101','F101','2018-07-31','Approved',2000,10000,'B1000');
Insert into EVENTREQUEST (EVENTNO,DATEHELD,DATEREQ,CUSTNO,FACNO,DATEAUTH,STATUS,ESTCOST,ESTAUDIENCE,BUDNO) values ('E107','2018-11-23','2018-07-28','C105','F100','2018-07-31','Denied',10000,5000,null);
```

Comment: What database are you using? This code works fine for MSSQL: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019l&fiddle=cdfb919aae0b2bc368b198941f0aefc8

Comment: Hi mrNone, Thanks for your reply. Im using PostgreSQL

Comment: It seems that i have managed to make it work now but another error has occured now that im unsure about how to solve

Comment: ERROR:  new row for relation "eventrequest" violates check constraint "eventrequest_status_check"
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (E101, 2018-10-26, 2018-07-28, F100, C100, null, Pending, 5000.00, 80000, B1000).
SQL state: 23514

Comment: I think your problem is with upper case and lower case. In CHECK constraint you wrote `pending` but in INSERT you wrote `Pending`. I suppose it's not the same in Postgresql.